# ie png fix - strecthing images

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, pngfix

In my new website, Im trying to Implement iepngfix with the below code.

```
img, div { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
```

But Unfortunately, the images i added in the website is being stretched in ie6. i did'nt gave any value to ie. but the width is 100%. when i remove the png fix code i mentioned early, then the images looks correct. but the png fix won't work.

I think some code is ruuning in the png fix htc file. so that its being stretched.

Is there any Solutions for that ??

Answer (score 1):

try [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/)

Comment: This is the best PNG fix by far. Although not maintained anymore, it's the best i've used.